# When call populate TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to add load Student by name and populate all data.
My Student Schema looks like

```
// Exam Schema
var ExamSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    mark: String,
    teacher: String,
    activated: Date
});

// Student Schema
var StudentSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    exams: [ExamSchema],
    activated: Date
});
```

I added to StudentSchema statics function

```
  loadByName: function (name, cb) {
    this.findOne({ name : name})
      .populate('exams')
      .exec(cb)
  },
```

ad When I call I get error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
    at model.populate [as _populate]
```

when I commented populate line I get Student but exams list was empty.
How to find One student by name and populate all exams for that student ?

Answer (score 2):

The issue you're having is that `populate` is for when you've linked to another document by reference, where as the *exams* field in your schema is an array of subdocuments. They should contain the full information automatically.

See the documentation pages on population (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) and subdocuments (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) for more information.